# Prime Numbers In a given range in Java

Tags: java, loops, numbers, primes

I am trying to take the input from the user for a range and then finding all the prime numbers in that range. I am using the logic that any nuber that is greater than 2 and less than itself, which is not divisible by any number in this range (2 to less than itself) is a prime number.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the range : ");
        int n1=sc.nextInt();
        int n2=sc.nextInt();
        int fl=0;
        for(int i=n1;i<n2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
            { 
                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    fl=1;
                }
            }
            if(fl == 0)
                System.out.println(i);
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is the output I am getting:
1
2
3

When the range is 1 to 20 (No more than 3).
Please help me out.

Comment: This is a case where you would benefit from learning and applying the [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) technique.   Seriously.   Debugging your own code is a skill that is essential for a programmer.

Comment: There are many fine examples of computing prime numbers on this site.  I recommend you search for them.  And as you go thru your code, decide what a value should be based on your logic.  Then put in a print statement to see if that is true.  The best, first step toward debugging is to use print statements.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely learn the rubber duck debugging. I tried printing the values at each stage to get to the wrong part of my code but that did not yield anything fruitful. I also searched online and understood their solutions But I wanted to implement them this way. Thank you so much for your help I will surely follow your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Turamarth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457643/turamarth), you need to reset the flag at each iteration. I also suggest you to loop until `i <= n2`, otherwise you would miss the last number, and add an input check.

```java
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    boolean flag;
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the range: ");
    n1 = sc.nextInt();
    n2 = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
    
    if (n1 < 2)
        n1 = 2;
    if (n2 < 2)
    {
        System.out.println("No prime numbers in range.");
        return;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Result: ");
    for(int i = n1; i <= n2; i++)
    {
        flag = false;
        for(int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        { 
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(!flag)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Example with [1, 19]:

```
Enter the range: 1 19
Result: 
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
```

#### Optimizations

Consider that:

- you could break out from the second loop when you find a divisor (`i % j == 0`), by putting a `break;` statement inside the if condition;
- after 2 all prime numbers are odd, therefore when `i >= 3` you can increase it by 2: `i += 2`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I see the problem now I guess initialising the flag variable within the outer 'i' loop will help to solve the problem and reduce the space complexity as well. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your flag `fl` back to 0 at the start of every iteration of the outer loop.
At the moment once you encounter a non-prime (i.e. 4) it will set the value to 1 and then keep it for the remaining numbers.